# TempData is null on RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I am using `TempData` to pass some data from one Cotroller Action to another Controller Action, It was working fine till few days back. Now it is null on RedirectToAction.

Here is my code:

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostWidget(WidgetType type, int? timeFrame, int offset = 0)
{
    TempData["PostWidgetRoute"] = true;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Query", null);
}
```

**QueryController**

```
public ViewResult Index(string id = "", string queryType = "Query")
{      
   var data= TempData["PostWidgetRoute"];
   return view();
}
```

Not getting what might be the reason behind sudden change in behaiviour of tempdata variable.

Comment: I have checked your code  running  in a test application. Its working as expected!  It is strange that it is not working on your side.

Comment: :( hmmm.... I am getting null value.

Comment: May be any other thing coming into play!

Comment: `TempData` issue sometimes related with cookies, are you changed cookie settings recently? Your current code looks fine at the moment I tested it.

Comment: Actually, one ajax call was occuring and thats why tempdata was null. I managed to remove that ajax call.